# Reading incoming Headers on aspx page code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, http-headers

There is a process that will send an http post request to a specific url, and from there I need to read information stored in the request headers (specifically X-RIM-Push-ID and X-RIM-Push-Status)

Is it possible to read the headers using IIS 6?

I'm planning on using:

var id = Response.Headers["X-RIM-Push-ID"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for request headers in ASP.NET:

```
var id = Request.Headers["X-RIM-Push-ID"];
```

> Is it possible to read the headers using IIS 6?

Hmm, usually it's your application that should read headers, not sure what you mean here.

Comment: I tried to use that code, but when debuggin I got an exception that said I need to have Integrated Pipeline. Looking it up I started seeing a lot of pages saying how you need it and that cassini doesnt have it, now im worried if we are gonna be able to use it, since our production servers use IIS6

Comment: @Francisco Noriega, who said that? What exception did you get? Integrated Pipeline is a notion that exists on IIS 7.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Visual studio says it :/  here's a snapshot: http://www.use.com/7058f941b9c1a0083a54

Comment: @Francisco Noriega, you are using `Response.Headers` in this screenshot. Now look at my answer once again please. Notice the difference? Hint: `Request.Headers`.

Comment: Thanks... could have just pointed out that in the answer though.. no need for the attitude

Comment: @Francisco Noriega, I just thought that posting source code in the answer would be sufficient. I apologize if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need IIS7 running in pipeline mode.  See this msdn article. [See this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers.aspx)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

We can use reflection and can be read the response headers

```
        try
        {
            var header = HttpContext.Current.Response;

            header.AppendHeader("test0", "1");
            header.AppendHeader("test1", "2");
            header.AppendHeader("test2", "2");
            header.AppendHeader("test3", "3");
            header.AppendHeader("test4", "4");


            MethodInfo dynMethod = header.GetType().GetMethod("GenerateResponseHeaders", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var result =  dynMethod.Invoke(header, new object[] { false });
        }
        catch (HttpRequestValidationException ex)
        {
            string str = ex.Message;
        }
```